# What is the difference between un-authenticated and authenticated MPNS?

Tags: authentication, windows-phone-8, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, mpns

Only difference I found is that the un-authenticated MPNS have a limited amount of daily push notifications, I'm afraid about that another difference is this that un-authentication don't recognize the end-user. I'm right or wrong with this one?
Or maybe there is other difference between this two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unauthenticated MPNS Push are limited to 500 per day while authenticated MPNS Push are not throttled and authenticated push are delivered to MPNS via SSL connections that are established using a certificate issued by Microsoft trusted root CA authority.

Comment: And this is only difference between this two?

Comment: Right. Thats the only difference.